# Is there a way to search sensory data stored in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, search, search-engine

I have a table where I have multiple of columns with sensory data such as the temperature. I wanted to ask if there's an existing way to search for the data available in the table using a search bar that inputs the user's query (edit: this basically mean that the user can input any textual query, but how can the query be translated to something useful in a table full of sensory data?) I have already done my research but I couldn't find any decent results. Bellow is the description of the table:

[image]

As you can see, this table mainly have numerical values, except for the names of the columns and the Client and datetime columns.

Comment: Please explain what you mean by "using a search bar"? Of course there are ways to search for anything, but everything depends on what exactly you want to do.

Comment: Editing. Thank you for your suggestion.

Comment: Done. I hope this explains it better.

Answer (score 1):

Yes there are multiple ways.
You could prompt the user to specify different criteria for the search, for example:

- DateRange
- Client
- TempRange
- Status

And many more, this way you can filter the data to get only what you are looking for; but from what I can understand in your question is that you want a single search box with a single input to search in multiple fields, if that is the case you will need to filter on each one of the fields you are interested in, using the OR operator and some data type conversion.

```
--your parameters and temporary variables to perform conversion
DECLARE @criteria VARCHAR(20) = '55';
DECLARE @criteria_temp INT = 0;

--try conversions here
BEGIN TRY
SET @criteria_temp = CONVERT(int,@criteria,0);
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
SET @criteria_temp = 0;
END CATCH

--your query
SELECT * FROM MyTable
WHERE
Client LIKE '%'+@criteria+'%' OR
TEMP = @criteria_temp
```

You can see that this query will retrieve all the record where Client contains '55' and records where the TEMP is equal to 55.

If the user inputs the string 'test' as the criteria the conversion for `@criteria_temp` will fail, int this case you can use a default value, for example 0 and the query will return all records where Client contains 'test' and records where temp is equal to 0.

Based on this you can add more variables for different datatypes and search conditions in the query.

Comment: My apologies for the delay. I guess defining certain parameters should be a better idea as it will result in accurate results and easier interaction with the user. So, in case I filter the search, then it will solely depend on me how I want to restrict the layout right? But in case the user didn't want to specify a specific date for his query then that will increase the search space exponentially, which means slower respond time, any way to solve this? P.S: is that MySQL coding?

Comment: It depends on the scenario, places like google benefit from a single search  field since the criteria each user inputs can be so different i.e words, phrases, quotes, serial numbers, models, properties, website names, etc.,  and if the user needs to be more specific they can use advance search to add special criteria to the search. In your case you might benefit from having multiple search fields, or at least letting the user select in wish fields he/she wants to search, an example of this can be seen here http://www.vxsearch.com/screenshots/vxsearch_search_files.jpg

Comment: The provided code is actually from SQL Server, but i checked the syntax and works the same in MySQL